# Why is "as" casting not allowed with an explicit cast operator?

Tags: c#, casting

This is my code:

```
    public class GoodSuperDictionary
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> dicitionary;

        public GoodSuperDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
        {
            dicitionary = dic;
        }

        public static explicit operator GoodSuperDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
        {
            return new GoodSuperDictionary(dic);
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    GoodSuperDictionary dic2 = dic as GoodSuperDictionary; // compile error
    GoodSuperDictionary dic3 = (GoodSuperDictionary)dic; // good
```

I'd like the `compile error` line to run, but it seems that the `explicit operator` doesn't handle that kind of casting.

I'd like to know why this happens?
I'd also like to know if there's an `operator` that can allow the `as` casting to kick in?

Comment: _"The `as` operator cannot perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions"_: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Got you..Thank you..couldn't find the related post -> sorry for the duplicate..